# What will  be the default Python interpreter for 12.04?

Tags: python, 12.04

I don't even have Python 3 interpreter currently, and was surprised by this Wikipedia article: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Version_history_of_common_programs) while I searched for 12.04 release date.

It mentiones Python 3.2 as default Python interpreter in Ubuntu 12.04, while IMHO I wouldn't have expected Python 3 so soon.

Is Wikipedia information correct?

I found also this: [link](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-p/meeting/19777/foundations-p-python-versions/) but it's not clear as which would be default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.04 will probably have both 3.2 and 2.7 on the CD - the [plan](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-p-python-versions) is to port Update Manager to Python 3. Typing `python` at a command prompt will still get you Python 2.7, though.

I think the Wikipedia article is giving the most recent version which is installed by default, rather than the 'default Python interpreter'.

Answer (score 2):

To see what version of packages are in use in the different releases of Ubuntu, use http://packages.ubuntu.com.

[It shows](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python) that Python 3 is not the default in Precise. This site currently isn't suitable for questions of that kind, because this may change tomorrow. It's very difficult for us to manage when a correct answer becomes incorrect.